# 類型化しておいて. Should we translate this as "categorize" or "classify"?

Tags: word-usage

Full text: さらに検索エンジンの内部では、ユーザーがこれまでにサービスを利用した履歴を集めて興味の範囲が似ているユーザーを類型化しておいて、類型化された好みを検索結果の並べ方に反映します。

My understanding: Furthermore, the search engine's internal system collects the user's previous use of service, personal history to categorize it with similar ranges of interest, and then reflects these categorized preferences in a similar order of search results.

My Issue: 類型化しておいて. Should we translate this as "categorize" or "classify"?

Comment: I believe *categorize* and *classify* are largely interchangeable in English. To you, what's the important difference between the two?

Comment: @naruto To me _classify_ is to identify by or divide into classes and _categorize_ is to assign a category; to divide into classes.

Comment: Then they are interchangeable when they vaguely mean "to divide into classes", aren't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look for the context and the exact method they are using. If this article explicitly mentions predefined クラス or カテゴリ near this sentence, you probably should use *classify* or *categorize* accordingly. If that's not the case, this sentence is probably an explanation of [automatic clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#World_wide_web), so both *classify* and *categorize* work, but *group* may be enough, too.

Comment: Thank you. This fits best with the text.